# Remove mouse and keyboard activity if popup is displayed

Tags: javascript, html

i want to implement an automatic logout which does exactly what it is supposed to do. The popup should only appear when time x has expired. As long as you are active i.e. scrolling, typing, mouse movement and clicking the timer for opening the popup does not need to run.

This works fine but when the popup is open the session should only continue by clicking on the button in the popup otherwise the session will be logged out automatically after another timer.

In the following my code so far

**Javascript**

```
// Set timeout variables.
var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;
var inactivity;

function resetTimerByActivity () {
    // console.log("resetTimerByActivity");
    console.log("inactivity: " + inactivity);
    if(!inactivity) {
        alert("alert");
        window.onmousemove = resetAutoLogoutTimer; // catches mouse movements
        window.onmousedown = resetAutoLogoutTimer; // catches mouse movements
        window.onclick = resetAutoLogoutTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
        window.onscroll = resetAutoLogoutTimer;    // catches scrolling
        window.onkeypress = resetAutoLogoutTimer;  //catches keyboard actions
    }
}

// Start warning timer.
function startAutoLogoutTimer() {
    console.log("startAutoLogoutTimer");
    inactivity = 0;
    warningTimer = setTimeout("autoLogoutIdleWarning()", 30000);
    resetTimerByActivity();
}  

// Reset timers.
function resetAutoLogoutTimer() {
    console.log("resetAutoLogoutTimer");
    window.location = '#';
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    startAutoLogoutTimer();
}

// Show idle timeout warning dialog.
function autoLogoutIdleWarning() {
    console.log("autoLogoutIdleWarning");
    inactivity = 1;
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    resetTimerByActivity();
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("AutoLogoutIdleTimeout()", 30000);
    window.location = '#popupLogoutWarning';
}

// Logout the user.
function AutoLogoutIdleTimeout() {
    console.log("AutoLogoutIdleTimeout");
    window.location = '/logout';
}
```

**Popup**

```
<div id="popupLogoutWarning" class="popup-overlay">
    <div class="popup-popup">
        <h2>Auto-Logout</h2>
        <div class="popup-content" style="background:#e3f7fc;border:1px solid #8ed9f6;padding:20px;">
            <p>You will be logged out in ten seconds. Click "Stay Logged In" to prevent this.</p>
            <p><input type="button" name="autologoutStayLoggedIn" id="autologoutStayLoggedIn" value="Stay Logged In" class="admin-button" onclick="resetAutoLogoutTimer();" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popup-box {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    padding: 35px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px/50px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-align: center;
}

.popup-button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #06D85F;
    border-radius: 20px/50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.popup-button:hover {
    background: #06D85F;
}

.popup-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9999999999;
}
.popup-overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.popup-popup {
    margin: 70px auto;
    top: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup-popup h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup-popup .popup-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: all 200ms;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
.popup-popup .popup-close:hover {
    color: #06D85F;
}
.popup-popup .popup-content {
    max-height: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

In the template the function startAutoLogoutTimer is started after the page has been loaded.

Comment: @CalvinNunes I meant Javascript of course

Comment: So your functionality is working fine, only thing you require is to build an element with maximum z-index and position fixed to cover your screen.  Place your button in it and simply call it when triggered.

Comment: @DhavalChheda Edited my post. Popup contains content and button. CSS contains position and z-index. If popup appears and I move/click with the mouse it disappear. Push a button on keyboard it disappears too

Comment: Can you inspect and see if you are interacting with the element behind your overlay or the overlay itself ? And one more thing, in your console can you check if it because of using window object, that your clicks are triggering to hide the overlay ?

Comment: Solved it ... Added an else to my if and set every movement null and it worked out

Comment: Glad it worked out.